# User Id is not passing through Ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, model-view-controller, counter

I am creating view counter in laravel, so here is the situation, I created small cards for customer listing, if some press "view" button the card is expand and also count as view.

I used Buefy in front-end so card is expanding whenever I press the view, I also add onclick event and pass the current user id of particular card, after the click it will call to AJAX function which will increment by +1 in view_counter column.
But Ajax is not pass id to the controller, I tried alert which is working fine, that means my syntax is wrong.

Here is my view: network.blade.php

```
                      <button
                            onclick='viewUpdate("{{$user->id}}")'
                            class="button is-primary"
                            slot="trigger"
                            aria-controls="contentIdForA11y1" 
                            >
                              View!
                      </button>
```

My Ajax script:

```
 <script>
   function viewUpdate(val) 
   {
    //alert(val);
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('dne/viewincrement') }}",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      'id': val
    },
    success: function(result){
    console.log('success');
    }
   });
  }
 </script>
```

As per my knowledge when someone click on button, it will send the user id of that card and in the script which will store in viewUpdate(val), now I passing that value of Id to the controller.

This is my Route:

```
    Route::prefix('dne')->group(function() {
     Route::post('/viewincrement', 'DNE\DNEFrontController@count');
    }
```

and this my Controller: DNEFrontController.php

```
   public function count(Request $request)
   {
    //dd($request);
    $user = DNEUser::findOrFail($id);
    if(isset($user) && !empty($user)){
      $user->view_counter+=1;
      $user->save();
     }
     //$this->addData('user', $user);
    return $this->getView('dne.customer.pizza');
    }
```

view_counter is my column which is 0 by default, it will increment by +1.
Current situation: Button is working & Ajax is called, it will show the id value in alert but in console it throws:

POST http://localhost:8000/dne/viewincrement 419 (unknown status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you using POST request you might need to send csrf _token  with your request or you can try out GET request

Answer (score 0):

when you pass it on ajax its gonna be request therefore you should call it like this

```
$request->id
```

hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to

`$user = DNEUser::findOrFail($id);`

to

```
$user = DNEUser::findOrFail($request->id);
```

**Extra read:**

> The findOrFail and firstOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a  `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown:

If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

419 status code says token not found or token expired.
So you can use two methods for pass token:- 
1. Pass with data:-

```
data: {
  'id': val,
  '_token': "csrf_token"
},
```

You need to repeat it every time when you call an ajax with the post.

2. Setup in the header:-
   You need to setup it once it will work for all. no need to set up again.

```
if (s.type == "POST") {
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
}
});
```